# How to use a loop to return multiple results for a single table row

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm writing a script to create a `.csv` to enroll users in a VLE course. Mostly, each user has one VLE course, but some users have multiple VLE courses to be enrolled in. I need my script to create multiple results rows when a user is on a program that requires them to be enrolled on multiple courses.

I have looked at while loops using variables but can't get my head around the logic required.

Table

```
ID         AOS   Session  Year
------------------------------
741258     BATP    CC2      2
456789     BATP    TS1      1
963741     BATP    SM3      3
456123     BATP    PM2      2
687459     MACP    CP1      1
753951     MAAS    AS1      1
```

Query:

```
select 
    'ENROLL' as [Type],
    bio.student_id as [ID],
    'Student' as [Role],
    case 
       --Course offering
       when AOS = 'batp' and Year = '1' then 'TP-F-TP1'
       when AOS = 'batp' and Year  = '2' then 'TP-F-TP2'
       when AOS = 'batp' and Year  = '3' then 'TP-F-TP3'
       else 'XXX'
    end as [Course Offering Code]
```

Then I need it for each of those when AOS = 'batp' to return a second row

```
case
   when AOS = 'batp' and Session = 'CC' then 'TP-F-CC'
   when AOS = 'batp' and Session = 'SM' then 'TP-F-SM'
   when AOS = 'batp' and Session = 'PM' then 'TP-F-PM'
   else 'XXX'
end as [Course Offering Code]
```

So I'd like to have results like this

```
Type     ID       Role       Course Offering Code
-------------------------------------------------
ENROLL   741258   Student    TP-F-TP2
ENROLL   741258   Student    TP-F-CC
```

Comment: You can use [`union all`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to combine the results of two `select` statements into one set of result rows.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about your complete logic, but for the provided samples, you can use UNION ALL for that no need for loops

Example :

```
DECLARE @tb TABLE (ID INT, AOS VARCHAR(50), Session VARCHAR(50), Year INT)
INSERT INTO @tb 
VALUES 

(741258, 'BATP', 'CC2', 2),
(456789, 'BATP', 'TS1', 1),
(963741, 'BATP', 'SM3', 3),
(456123, 'BATP', 'PM2', 2),
(687459, 'MACP', 'CP1', 1),
(753951, 'MAAS', 'AS1', 1)

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        [Type] = 'ENROLL'
    ,   ID
    ,   [Role] = 'Student'
    ,   CourseOffer = 
        CASE 
            WHEN LOWER(AOS) = 'batp' AND [Year] = 1 THEN 'TP-F-TP1'
            WHEN LOWER(AOS) = 'batp' AND [Year] = 2 THEN 'TP-F-TP2'
            WHEN LOWER(AOS) = 'batp' AND [Year] = 3 THEN 'TP-F-TP3'
            ELSE 'XXX'
        END 
    FROM @tb
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        'ENROLL'
    ,   ID
    ,   'Student'
    ,   CourseOffer = 
        CASE 
            WHEN LOWER(AOS) = 'batp' AND LEFT([Session],2) = 'CC' THEN 'TP-F-CC'
            WHEN LOWER(AOS) = 'batp' AND LEFT([Session],2) = 'SM' THEN 'TP-F-SM'
            WHEN LOWER(AOS) = 'batp' AND LEFT([Session],2) = 'PM' THEN 'TP-F-PM'
            ELSE 'XXX'
        END 
    FROM @tb
) D 
WHERE 
    ID = 741258
ORDER BY ID
```

I think there is an easier way to do it with one set, just you need to know the complete logic which will make it possible.

Comment: Ah ha! Great stuff. Thanks for your insight.